# undefinded method when I add user's name to comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`@user.name` works on my posts, user profile, and everywhere else on my site. But when I add it to user comments, I get undefined method?

```
<p class="comment_body">
  <h2><%= @user.name %></h2>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>
```

I tried `<%= user.name %>` and still an error.

I tried `<%= current_user.name %>` and it worked. However, I don't want to show the current user's name, I want to see the user's name of who posted the comment.

EDIT:

I forgot to associate user to comment, but I'm not really sure how.

Comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:body))

    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

I went into my comments.rb and wrote `belongs_to :user` and in my user.rb I added `has_many :comments`.

Comment: Please show us the corresponding controller action. Presumably you aren't declaring the `@user` variable in the controller (or it gets assigned a `nil` value).

Comment: please also share the view code containing these lines

Comment: Could you add the complete error output please?

Answer (score 0):

So, should you set the user and save the comment, shouldn't you? try something like

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:body))
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      # something else
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you mean, like add "name" to comments model?

Comment: No. Don't you have an association from comment to user?

Comment: OHHHHH! I'm so stupid! I totally forgot about that. I added an association from comment to post and forgot about associating the user. lol I can fix this now. Thanks! I'll make u as answer

Comment: I am new to rails and having trouble, please see edit :)

Comment: I updated my answer. Anyway, it would be helpful if you wrote what doesn't work or the errors you have